# KeePass2 unable to auto-type into Cygwin or Git Bash (windows 10)

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, cygwin, keepass

I am using KeePass2 v.2.37 to save my different logins to virtual machines and servers.

I seem to recall that I was able to use auto-type with KeePass to ssh with Cygwin and Git Bash, but I have been unable to do it for atleast a few months. Auto-type works as it should in Notepad and windows cmd, so I know that KeePass is sending keys correctly to the focused window. I can also see that KeePass is able to focus the terminal windows, as both Cygwin and Git Bash will "light up" if they were the last focused windows when I press auto-type.

I'm using mintty and xterm256 for Cygwin and Git Bash. Not sure if that could be the cause.

Comment: Is there a way to change KeePass's autotype options? Maybe it's waiting for some specific prompt it can't see, if it is try changing it to just start typing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around I found this answer on sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/c2c55567/#dfe8

> You can't Auto-type into process which run with rights elevation.
>   Windows doesn't allow such communication. One solution is running
>   KeePass with higher rights

I realized that I sometime ago changed my Cygwin and Git Bash shortcuts to automatically open in administrator mode. Apparently, KeePass can't auto-type into a window that has admin rights unless KeePass itself is also run in admin mode. The solution is to either stop running the terminal windows in admin mode, or start running KeePass in admin mode.